# How can I delete a file with images in s3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am new to web development and new to using s3.  Im using node.js to delete files in s3, which I am able to do, but i run into trouble when a file has things inside it, like images or more files.  I don't get any errors when I try and delete the files with things inside.  I heard I had to add some metadata, but im not sure what type of metadata needs to be added.  Is there any good example on how I would be able to delete those files?

Comment: S3 doesn't care what is "inside" a *file,* so I wonder if you actually mean a *folder*.  With S3 you have to delete everything individually.

Comment: yes its a folder, is their a way to delete everything individually??